# Issue with creating Java Object from ChatGpt (OpenAI) api response using theokanning library

Tags: java, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm using the latest theokanning java library (0.18.2). My goal is to get a response from open ai api and convert it into a hierarchical java object. Here is my java code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Articles {
    
    @JsonPropertyDescription("the type of the article")
    private String articleType;
    @JsonPropertyDescription("list for the articles")
    private List<ArticleDetail> articleDetails;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ArticalDetail {
    
    @JsonPropertyDescription("article headline")
    private String headline;
    @JsonPropertyDescription("array of the article summary")
    private List<String> articleSummary;

}


public void createArticleDetails(String place, String topic) {
        // @formatter:off
        
        ChatFunction getArticleFunction = ChatFunction.builder()
                .name("getArticle")
                .description("You are an API server that provides articles in JSON format. Don't say anything else. Respond only with the JSON")
                .executor(Articles.class, ip -> { 
                    Articles art = new Articles();
                    art.setArticleType(ip.getArticleType());
                    art.setArticleDetails(ip.getArticleDetails());
                    return art;})
                .build();
        FunctionExecutor artFunctionExecutor = new FunctionExecutor(Collections.singletonList(getArticleFunction));
        List<ChatMessage> messages = List.of(new ChatMessage(ChatMessageRole.USER.value(), "I want to get top 5 articles about science));
        ChatCompletionRequest chatCompletionRequest = ChatCompletionRequest
                .builder()
                .model("gpt-4-1106-preview")
                .messages(messages)
                .functions(artFunctionExecutor.getFunctions())
                .functionCall(new ChatCompletionRequestFunctionCall("auto"))
                .temperature(0.8)
                .n(1)
                .build();
        
        ChatMessage responseMessage = chatGptService.createChatCompletion(chatCompletionRequest).getChoices().get(0).getMessage();
        ChatFunctionCall functionCall = responseMessage.getFunctionCall();
        JsonNode articlesNode = artFunctionExecutor.executeAndConvertToJson(functionCall);
        processArticle(articlesNode);
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Below is the error log:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.vo.ArticalDetail` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('None')
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "articleDetails" : {
    ....
```

It looks like the response is not in the same format as I'm expecting. I need to provide the inputs differently or add few additional configuration details?